# Converting unsigned to signed integers (Using Excel formulas or Power Query)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unsigned-integer, signed-integer

I have a list of unsigned 32-bit unsigned integers that actually are supposed to represent 32-bit signed integers.
For example 62714 = binary 1111010011111010 = signed -2822 when interpreted as two's complement
Basically I am trying find some formula to get from 62714 to -2822

The solution listed here does not seem to work:  https://ocroquette.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/converting-unsigned-to-signed-integers-using-powershell-or-excel/

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using 16 bit signed integers, so you could do:

```
=MOD(A1+2^15,2^15)-2^15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(BITAND(A1,32768)=32768,A1-65536,A1)
```

Examples:

1. If cell `A1 = 64973 (hex value FDCD)`then above returns -563
2. If cell `A1 = 1000 (hex value 03E8)` then above returns 1000

Useful functions to convert text hex strings to decimal and back: `HEX2DEC` and `DEC2HEX`